# Moisturized laptop makes clicking noise -- without HDD, main fan stopped

Tags: laptop, noise, water-damage

I have an Acer Aspire v5 121 laptop (netbook) what I've got moisturized. The keyboard isn't working but it worked from the USB mouse. I switched off completely but without keyboard I can't switch it on again. I disassembled it (battery and main cover removed) to dry out. I noticed that it makes some regular clicking noise even with HDD removed. The main fan doesn't rotating. What can clicking? Have you got any idea what to do? (It isn't working. Warranty is over, I'll go with it to an specialist, but who?)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser - be sure to take the tour at https://superuser.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: How do you define "moisturized?"  Was it left out in the rain, or dropped in the swimming pool, left outside for days, or what?  Perhaps a woman actually slathered it with moisturizing cream.  In any case, the symptoms sound bad.  Your best bet is to try to preserve the HDD if there are files on there that are important.

Comment: If the fan has seized then it could make clicking noises when it tries to start rotating. Can you turn it by hand?

Comment: clicking could also be from electrical arcing.

Comment: My wife "cleaned" it by some liquid. The main fan can be rotated by hand easily... seems normal. The clicking sound comes from the opposite side of the notebook (where the ethernet slot lies). P

Comment: Electrical arcing? I thinked about, but It's too regular to do that.. I hope that this is not the case.

Comment: I'm sorry I made that insensitive joke about a woman.  Anybody could have done that.  -->  Meanwhile, preserve that HDD.  You might want to pick up an enclosure that will allow you to plug it into the USB port of another computer and at least see if your files are accessible.